# Angular 10 / How to share 1 variable between 1 file with 2 classes / Angular Material Dialog component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I´m using Angular Material Dialog component, which has this structure:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

export interface DialogData {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
}

/**
* @title Dialog Overview
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

 animal: string;
 name: string;

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

openDialog(): void {
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
   width: '250px',
   data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
});

 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
   console.log('The dialog was closed');
   this.animal = result;
   });
 }
}

 @Component({
     selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
     templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
   })
   export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

   constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}

    onNoClick(): void {
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }

 }
```

As you can see it has 2 classes but only the 1º class is included into the father component .html

```
 <app-filter-modal [requestForm]="requestForm" [name]="name" 
 [animal]="animal"></app-filter-modal>
```

I need to link through out an @Input, a father component variable with the 2º class (the class which create the modal window itself) varible with the same name:

```
[requestForm]="requestForm"
```

But I got an error as I can not include the above line inside the 2º class selector as Angular Material Dialog doesn´t work like that.

How could relate the father component variable **requestForm** with the 2º class Angular Material Dialog variable with the same name (**requestForm**). My first idea was to share the variable between both classes within the file which includes both.

Comment: You can pass data into "DialogOverviewExample " component via Input decorator and from there pass the data data into mat dialog component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just like you did with "name" and "animal". (although the @Input decorators are missing)

Add the requestForm into the DialogData

```
export interface DialogData {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
  requestForm: any;
}
```

Create the input in the dialog opener component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {
 @Input() requestForm: string;
```

Send to the dialog when opening it

```
openDialog(): void {
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
   width: '250px',
   data: {
     name: this.name, 
     animal: this.animal,
     requestForm: this.requestForm
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your idea works, but its also necessary to inject the data object on the dialog class´ constructor:                                                                                  
  export class YourDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {name: string}) { }
}